# Where do I insert jsfiddle code in raw html

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to build raw html file where I will provide json dynamically:

Below is the code genrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmmulani/7MRx6/):

```
var myList=[{"name" : "abc", "age" : 50},
            {"age" : "25", "hobby" : "swimming"},
            {"name" : "xyz", "hobby" : "programming"}];

// Builds the HTML Table out of myList json data from Ivy restful service.
 function buildHtmlTable() {
     var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList);

     for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
         var row$ = $('<tr/>');
         for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
             var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];

             if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }

             row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
         }
         $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
     }
 }

 // Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.
 // Need to do union of keys from all records as some records may not contain
 // all records
 function addAllColumnHeaders(myList)
 {
     var columnSet = [];
     var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

     for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
         var rowHash = myList[i];
         for (var key in rowHash) {
             if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1){
                 columnSet.push(key);
                 headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
             }
         }
     }
     $("#excelDataTable").append(headerTr$);

     return columnSet;
 }
```

I have tried created a `table.html` as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test-isla.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
<div id="back">
<div class="red" id="div1"></div>
<div class="red1" id="div2"></div>
<div class="red2" id="div3"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

       var myList=[{"name" : "abc", "age" : 50},
            {"age" : "25", "hobby" : "swimming"},
            {"name" : "xyz", "hobby" : "programming"}];

// Builds the HTML Table out of myList json data from Ivy restful service.
 function buildHtmlTable() {
     var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList);

     for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
         var row$ = $('<tr/>');
         for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
             var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];

             if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }

             row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
         }
         $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
     }
 }

 // Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.
 // Need to do union of keys from all records as some records may not contain
 // all records
 function addAllColumnHeaders(myList)
 {
     var columnSet = [];
     var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

     for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
         var rowHash = myList[i];
         for (var key in rowHash) {
             if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1){
                 columnSet.push(key);
                 headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
             }
         }
     }
     $("#excelDataTable").append(headerTr$);

     return columnSet;
 }
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Issue is that this `table.html` doesn't show me proper table, can anyone point me what exactly is the issue. I'm newbie in html code.

**Answer :** [Edit]

The answer of @Unihedron was correct the only issue is the output was print 2 times as [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1g38txe14qv1880/table.html?dl=0)

I just replaced below line

```
  function buildHtmlTable(myList) {
```

in  @Unihedron code and it worked !!!

Comment: generally people go other way around ;)

Comment: @itachi i need to embed with android code so i m lokking into this format of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jsfiddle, right click on the "Result" box where your output is. Use "inspect element" in your browser (it's present even for Internet Explorer, so any modern one will do) and it will bring you the node of the element you've selected.

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/16ea9ed731640e1b522d23fda62139e9.png))</sub>

Go up a few levels until you find the `#document` signature, select and copy it. For your code, it will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html hc="b3"><script type="text/javascript">window["_gaUserPrefs"] = { ioo : function() { return true; } }</script><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo by manishmmulani</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    th {
    font-weight : bold
}
  </style>



<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 

var myList=[{"name" : "abc", "age" : 50},
            {"age" : "25", "hobby" : "swimming"},
            {"name" : "xyz", "hobby" : "programming"}];

// Builds the HTML Table out of myList json data from Ivy restful service.
 function buildHtmlTable() {
     var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList);

     for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
         var row$ = $('<tr/>');
         for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
             var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];

             if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }

             row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
         }
         $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
     }
 }

 // Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.
 // Need to do union of keys from all records as some records may not contain
 // all records
 function addAllColumnHeaders(myList)
 {
     var columnSet = [];
     var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

     for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
         var rowHash = myList[i];
         for (var key in rowHash) {
             if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1){
                 columnSet.push(key);
                 headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
             }
         }
     }
     $("#excelDataTable").append(headerTr$);

     return columnSet;
 }
//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body onload="buildHtmlTable()">

<table id="excelDataTable" border="1">
 <tbody><tr><th>name</th><th>age</th><th>hobby</th></tr><tr><td>abc</td><td>50</td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td>25</td><td>swimming</td></tr><tr><td>xyz</td><td></td><td>programming</td></tr></tbody></table>







</body></html>
```

Comment: showing result 2 times --> output as below : https://www.dropbox.com/s/1g38txe14qv1880/table.html?dl=0